# Identityserver4 doesn't revoke access tokens when calling end_session_endpoint

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

After a successful signout from identity server 4 (I see the log message AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed out.), The actual access token is still valid. Hence, with this access token, I can still access my APIs.

I can invalidate these tokens myself by calling:

```cs
_persistedGrantService.RemoveAllGrantsAsync(logoutContext.SubjectId, null, logoutContext.SessionId);
```

but I wonder if this is the right approach since I'm expecting that by calling the end_session_endpoint this administration would be handled by the identity server.
Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

My sign out method looks like this:

```cs
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
var logoutContext = await _interactionService.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
if (logoutContext == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

// Is this needed?
await _persistedGrantService.RemoveAllGrantsAsync(logoutContext.SubjectId, null, logoutContext.SessionId);

SignOutIframeUrl = logoutContext.SignOutIFrameUrl;

var externalIdp = await GetExternalIdpAsync();
if (externalIdp != null)
{
    // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
    // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
    // complete our single sign-out processing.
    var url = Url.Page("SignOut", new {logoutId});

    // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = url}, externalIdp);
}

if (logoutContext.PostLogoutRedirectUri != null)
{
    return Redirect(logoutContext.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
}

return Page();
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you are not supposed to return any view/data from your signout method. Instead the SignOutAsync handles that for you internally.

So, it could look something like this:

```
    public async Task DoLogout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I follow the instructions from http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout_external_providers.html. Can you please explain how your remark relates to the code that is proposed there, because they, like me, do return view/data from the signout method

Comment: ah, mine is used when you use the AddOpenIDConnect Client, not with IdentityServer, so it might be different there...